# Реализация вложенных элементов в ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Как раскидать имена по различным группам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Json - файл

```
 [
{
    "groupId":1,
    "groupName":"Семья",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"Иванов"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"Сидоров"
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"Петров"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"Мясников"
    }
    ]
},
{
    "groupId":2,
    "groupName":"Работа",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"Иванов"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"Сидоров"
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"Петров"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"Мясников"
    }
    ]
},
 {
    "groupId":3,
    "groupName":"Другие",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"Иванов"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"Сидоров"
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"Петров"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"Мясников"
    }
    ]
}]
```

Ajax - запрос

```
 $.ajax({ 
type: 'GET', 
url: 'json_data.json', 
data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) { 
    $.each(data, function(index, v) {
        $('#results').append("<div id='box2'><button class='submit tree' >+</button><button class='clear2 tree'>X</button><h3>"+data[index].groupName+"<span class='expand'>+</span></h3><ul class='ul'></ul></div>");
        $.each(data, function(v,k){
           $('<ul>').append("<li class='li'>"+data[index].members[v].nick+"</li>").appendTo('#results').appendTo('#box2'); 
       });
    });
}});
```

Comment: А можно код то же?

Comment: Обнови, я выложил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
{
    "groupId":1,
    "groupName":"Семья",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"Сидоров"
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"Петров"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"Мясников"
    }
    ]
},
{
    "groupId":2,
    "groupName":"Работа",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"Иванов"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"Сидоров"
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"Петров"
    }
    ]
},
 {
    "groupId":3,
    "groupName":"Другие",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"Иванов"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"Мясников"
    }
    ]
}]



        $.each(data, function(index, v) {
            $('#results').append("<div id='box2'><button class='submit tree' >+</button><button class='clear2 tree'>X</button><h3>"+data[index].groupName+"<span class='expand'>+</span></h3><ul class='ul group_ul_"+index+"'></ul></div>");
            $.each(v.members, function(v,k){
               $('<ul>').append("<li class='li'>"+data[index].members[v].nick+"</li>").appendTo('#results').appendTo('.group_ul_'+index); 
           });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'results'> </div>
```